# How can i run my python code from the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

In my current directory called `processing` i have many folders, one of them is called `segmentation`, there is many files in segmentation one of them is `test.py`. In my terminal i am in `processing` and i want to run `test.py` from there, i tried `python -m segmentation.test`  but this command didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Python script on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492214/how-to-run-python-script-on-terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the `processing` directory and want to run the `test.py` script inside the `segmentation` folder, simply do this:

```
python segmentation/test.py
```

Comment: got this error `python: can't open file 'segmentation/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`

Comment: Strange. Are you sure you are in the `processing` directory? Can you post the output of `ls`? And `ls segmentation`?

Comment: yes i'll try to restart it tends to get buggy at times.