# Using platformio-ide-terminal to run python code

Tags: python

How do I use platformio-ide-terminal to run python code within Atom?

I am only able to bring up a New Terminal using "+" at the bottom left side of the screen, but I cannot figure out how to run the code in the terminal within Atom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Python script on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492214/how-to-run-python-script-on-terminal)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
python3 YourFile.py
```

or

```
python YourFile.py
```

This also runs python in a normal terminal.
(The second command also works, but for me it defaults to python 2 in some cases)

See [How to run Python script on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492214/how-to-run-python-script-on-terminal).