# Python Execute in Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I am learning to program in Python, is there a way that I can execute the program.py so that it shows the results in the terminal window?

for example this is the code I have

```
temp = 6
freezing = 0
raining = False
hail = True
if hail == raining or (temp < freezing):
    print("Bad weather!")

if temp > freezing: 
    print("Not freezing")

k=input("press close to exit")
```

when I execute the command from cmdr (a terminal emulator) it opens a cmd window with the program, is there a way to have the output appear in the cmdr window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Python script on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492214/how-to-run-python-script-on-terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured out to type python3 program.py