# IndentationError when copying code into the Python REPL/Interpreter

Tags: python

I have a strange error. Why does it happen?

I write code, but Python shows me the error, but I don't see that error. I've attached the screenshot.

#### Code

```
def func(q):

    def funct(y):
        try:
            print(y)
            exit()

        except:
            pass

    funct(q)

a=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
for x in a:
    func(x)
```

#### Python

```
>>> def func(q):
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>     def funct(y):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def funct(y):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         try:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    try:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             print(y)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(y)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             exit()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    exit()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>>         except:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    except:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pass
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>>     funct(q)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    funct(q)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>> a=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
>>> for x in a:
...     func(x)
...
```

Notepad++:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can send the file itself? Screenshot looks fine for me.

Comment: The REPL has no way of knowing whether a block continues after 1,2,3,...,n blank lines. Thus, one blank line marks the end of a block on the REPL.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP II use copy/paste, I write in Notepad++ copy to clipboard, paste in  Python window. I use Windows Notepad++ and Linux Python. I can make a file if you not enough of this info.

Comment: @kirill I think you already got a correct answer. Didn't notice <stdin> is your file.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're copying and pasting the code into your command prompt, which is why it’s throwing you an error. When typing code in the "interactive Python" command line, if you leave a blank line Python interprets that as you having finished writing code, and executes it.

You're much better off saving your code in a `.py` file, and then in the command prompt using the command

```
python folder/to/your/file.py
```

which will run your code, and allow blank lines. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21492214/9063935) question for more information.

---

You could also **c**hange **d**irectory by using the [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) command in the command prompt like so:

```
cd folder/to/your
```

Which will "move" your command prompt into the folder containing your Python file. That way if you want to run your code, you only need to use:

```
python file.py
```